# Java JPA: ManyToMany relationship doesn't work

Tags: java, jpa, intellij-idea, many-to-many

I am developing simple web-app in IntelliJ using JPA. I have a database with 3 tables and these records:

```
Entity1    Entity1_Entity2     Entity2 
 ID:        Ref1:    Ref2:       ID:   
 1           1        2           1
 2           1        1           2
```

Also in Entity1_Entity2 table these relationships are specified:
(Ref1) -> Entity1(ID)
(Ref2) -> Entity2(ID)

Using JPA I created entities Entity1 and Entity2:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Entity1")
@Getter
@Setter
public class Entity1 implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private int id;      

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "Entity1_Entity2",
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "Ref1") },
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "Ref2") })
    private List<Entity2> list = new ArrayList<>();
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "Entity2")
@Getter
@Setter
public class Entity2 implements Serializable {

       @Id
       @Column(name = "ID")
       private int id;

       @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "list")
       private List<Entity1> otherList = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

My problem is that when I select an instance of Entity1(for example ID=1) and call entity1.getList(), it always returns null reference, but according to data - 2 objects of Entity2 should be returned.

Tried to change @JoinTable annotation to these values, but it didn't help:

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "Entity1_Entity2",
         joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "Ref1", referencedColumnName = "ID") },
         inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "Ref2", referencedColumnName = "ID") })


@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "Entity1_Entity2")


@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "Entity1_Entity2",
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "Ref1") },
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "Ref2") })
```

Comment: Are you calling getList() in transaction? Is it null referece to list or to list objects?
Try without initializing field with ArrayList

Comment: No, without transaction. It returns null to list, as it no list would be initialized. Also tried without list initialization, but it didn't work.

Comment: You have no id on entities. There are no primary keys defined. This entites can not be found in db.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include them when copying from my code. Updated question. Also, I have defined ID as primary keys on both tables.

Comment: can you try using [at]GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) with [at]Id ?

Comment: Also pls try removing [at]JoinTable annotation and test without it

Comment: @mibrahim.iti I tried all your advices: inserting GeneratedValue, changing "int" type to "Integer", removing "JoinTable", but result still is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem in using ***@Getter*** and ***@Setter***

Because next way working fine with me :)

Note: i didn't try using *@Getter* and *@Setter*

**Entity1**

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "Entity1")
public class Entity1 implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private int id;      

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "Entity1_Entity2",
             joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "Ref1", referencedColumnName = "ID") },
             inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "Ref2", referencedColumnName = "ID") })
    private List<Entity2> list = new ArrayList<>();

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public List<Entity2> getList() {
        return list;
    }

    public void setList(List<Entity2> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }
}
```

**Entity2**

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "Entity2")
public class Entity2 implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private int id;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "list")
    private List<Entity1> otherList = new ArrayList<>();

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public List<Entity1> getOtherList() {
        return otherList;
    }

    public void setOtherList(List<Entity1> otherList) {
        this.otherList = otherList;
    }

}
```

and it generated third table as expected with two columns (ref1, ref2)

anyway i am using JPA 2.1 with Hibernate provider, so doing next code would get what u expected.

> Entity1 entity1 = entityManager.find(Entity1.class, 1);
>
> entity1.getList();

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I managed to solve this problem by adding "Stateful" annotation to class where I was calling getList() method. Don't know how it helped and how this is related.

Comment: @Edd. [at]Stateless or [at]Stateful is just to give you an instance of class, it's not related to calling database, so for example using it above class will allow you to use [at]EJB YourClassName instance; without using = new YourClassName(); so server will manage instantiating an instance for you without using new keyword.